# Execute RAW SQL on DbContext in EF Core 2.1

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have [researched this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) and always found examples like this:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs")
    .ToList();
```

The problem is, I don't want to run my raw SQL on the Blogs table. Basically, I want to implement an interface like this:

```
bool ExecuteNonSafeSql(
    string connectionString,
    string sql);
```

Is there a way to do that with DbContext?

Comment: You would use methods of `context.Database` like `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` or `context.Database.SqlQuery()`. Which to use depends on what exactly you want to do. What would be the return value of your statement?

Comment: If the command was executed successfully, then a `true` is returned. Otherwise, a `false`.

Comment: What do you mean with "successful"? Can you give an example.

Comment: hmm in MySQL workbench, if I run a query (it doesn't matter if it is a select or an insert) I get a green check mark telling me it was successful and x rows were affected. So I guess I'm looking for the equivalent of the green tick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time of writing (EF Core 2.1), there is no way to execute arbitrary *sequence returning* SQL command.

Only entity types and [Query Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) are supported via `FromSql`.

So the closest solution is to define query type (a class holding the query result) and use `FromSql`, but it's not generic - the query types must be registered in the `DbContext` via fluent API and the method should receive a generic argument specifying that type, e.g

```
class ResultType
{
   // ...
}
```

then

```
modelBuilder.Query<ResultType>();
```

and finally

```
db.Query<ResultType>().FromSql(...)
```

Note that `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` can execute arbitrary SQL, but can't be used to return sequence (`IEnumerable<T>`, `IQueryable<T>`).

Comment: can I run something like `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {databaseName};` with the `.ExecuteSqlCommand`?

Comment: @J86 I think you can. Any scalar DDL, T-SQL, SP, batch etc. command. Just you can't get result from SP/function/batch containing/return  *SELECT …*

Answer (score 10):

You can use `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` to execute sql.

If you want to use `SqlCommand` you can get the connection by

```
var cnn = (SqlConnection) context.Database.GetDbConnection();
cnn.Open();
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
```

Comment: `ExecuteSqlCommand` will return the number of affected records. It will throw an exception when the statement cannot be executed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Database.SqlQuery()` directly to context.

Here i create a generic function that can execute your query directly with target to Database rather than entity.

```
public static List<T> Execute<T>(MyDbContext context, string query) where T : class
{
    var result = context.Database
                        .SqlQuery<T>(query)
                        .ToList();

    return result;
}
```

You can use above function like

```
var blogs = Execute<Blog>(context, "SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs");
```

Comment: Any sample for efcore?

Comment: @OlorunfemiAjibulu, I didn't found any solution right now. but [this](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#database.executesqlcommand) link may be what you want.