# Execute Raw SQL in EF Core 6.0.6

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I need to execute SQL Command in MS SQL, which is already connected via EF Core 6.0.6.

First thing I found is: [Execute RAW SQL on DbContext in EF Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517493/execute-raw-sql-on-dbcontext-in-ef-core-2-1)

So I tried this:

```
db.Database.Query<Question>("COMMAND");
```

But it says that `DatabaseFacade` does not contain the `Query<T>()` method. Same thing with these ones:

```
db.Query<Question>("COMMAND");

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("COMMAND");

db.Database.SqlQuery("COMMAND");

db.Database.GetDbConnection();
```

**A little explanation:**

1. `db` is an instance of the `ApplicationDbContext` class which inherits from `IdentityDbContext` from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` package
2. `Question` is my class, instances of which are stored in the `Questions` table in my database

So my main question is: `Is there a way of executing raw SQL in EF Core 6.0.6?`

I would be very grateful for any materials or tips in this matter.

Comment: Create Store Procedure and invoke it. It is for the best.

Comment: Can you share more code, to show more context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
var questions = db.Questions.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Questions").ToList();
```

Make sure that you have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` on top

Or if you have access to ApplicationDbContext via service provider you would try something like this:

```
var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SQL");
```

Comment: DbSet<Question> does not contain FromSqlRaw(). Maybe I am missing some package?

Comment: In my apps this works after using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Comment: Thanks a lot! When I downloaded the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package it started to work!

Comment: Now I tried without Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational and it works well too. Guess the whole thing was because I forgot to write using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore in the beginning. Anyway, thank you a lot)

Comment: Is there a method that returns a custom object (ex: the result from joining tables)